# How to solve problem using beautifulsoup with xml files with encode header

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have this problem using beautifulsoup in xml files with encode version

I have this file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>.....</project>
```

And the python code

```
for file in files:

print(dir + file)

infile = open( dir + file,"r")
contents = infile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, features ="xml")
print(soup.prettify())
```

The result is of the print is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

The project tag is ignored. It just happend in files that have the encoding in the first line

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')


print(soup)
```